# f-strings with variable width justification

Tags: python, python-3.9, f-string

I'm trying to write part of a logging function. As part of that I'm coding a function to print a formatted dictionary in the form:

```
key        : value
key1       : value
key63535   : value
```

to accommodate keys of different length while keeping alignment I'm using a left justified format string:

```py
f"{key_string:<20}: {value}"
```

However, I would like to change this so the width can be varied (as small widths don't fit long strings and long widths make things more difficult to read with short strings). I expected this would be a simple matter of changing the `20` to `var` but to my surprise python doesn't seem to support this. Could you please let me know how to achieve this?

Thanks.